# has_many :through formtastic multi-select field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I'm trying to set up a many to many relationship using the has_many :through method and then use a multi-select field to setup the relationships. I'm following this tutorial:

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/185-formtastic-part-2

However for some reason the form displays a strange hex number and it changes each page refresh, I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong. Below is my model/view code.

company.rb

```
has_many :classifications
has_many :sics, :through => :classifications
```

sic.rb

```
has_many :classifications
has_many :companies, :through => :classifications
```

classification.rb

```
belongs_to :company
belongs_to :sic
```

_form.html.erb

```
<% semantic_form_for @company do |f| %>
  <% f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :company %>
    <%= f.input :sics %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.buttons %>
<% end %>
```

Also here is the the form looks like it's showing the correct number of entries for the field but it is clearly not showing the correct name for the relationship.

[SIC Multi-Select http://web9.twitpic.com/img/103694166-98ad71116216d3d1b12dd77690b36248.4bf6ca20-full.jpg](http://web9.twitpic.com/img/103694166-98ad71116216d3d1b12dd77690b36248.4bf6ca20-full.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are seeing in the `to_s` method of an `ActiveRecord::Base` object. The hex number is the memory location which would be different each request.
After poking around the Formastic code, it looks for methods from a predefined list to find the text to display.

Make sure your `Sic` model has a field (or method) in this list `to_label, display_name, full_name, name, title, username, login, value, to_s` that returns the text you want.

Comment: You're brilliant that worked perfectly just added a field called name and it shows up just fine now. Thanks.